# current date with delay

Tags: vb.net, date

I writing application using vb .net.
In my application I got text box displaying current date.
As usually after midnight date is changing.
There is any chance  to set delay that date will change after 02:00 am next day ?

For example:

Today is 09/07/17 and I need that after midnight textbox will still show this date. But after 02:00 am ( 10/07/117 ) date will change for 10/07/17.

My current code:

```
  Private Sub HOMESCREEN_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SMARTSCREEN.MdiParent = Me
    SMARTSCREEN.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    SMARTSCREEN.Show()
    SMARTSCREEN.datee.Text = Date.Today()
    SMARTSCREEN.NOWEEK.Text = (DatePart("WW", Now))
```

Thanks,

Comment: I am from UK.  Reason why I need that delay is that we start our shift at work at 15:30 and we  should finish at midnight. But sometimes we got overtime and data which I will enter to my application after midnight need to be saved with yesterday date.

Answer (score 0):

The big (actually huge) question is, in what time zone is that 2:00 am you're talking about? You can easily achieve that by simply changing the time zone.

Say your time zone is **US Eastern Time -5**, then setting the time zone in your code to **US Mountain Time -7** will effectively give you the result you want.

**EDIT:** This is trivial, but since you mentioned that you're in UK, then I assume that your time zone is **London 0**, so set to **Coordinated Universal Time -2** to achieve what you want.

Alternatively, it can be simpler in your code to just subtract two hours:

```
SMARTSCREEN.datee.Text = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2).ToString("d")
```

Comment: As I just start with programming could you help me with that ? How i should change my code ?

Comment: When I use this code its show me like that:  08/07/2017 22:00:00 .That show when I open application now. So its will not work as I need.

Comment: Then use `ToString()` to format it anyway you want. For example `ToString("d")` gives you the short date format on your machine that you run your code on. See my updated answer.